# SQL Set all .JPG to .PNG

Tags: php, sql, image

how can i loop through all rows in a table, in mysql, and set all records in column 'pImage' that end in .JPG to end in .PNG?

Comment: You don't *loop* in SQL, you execute statements like `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...`.

Comment: alright, sorry, its been a late day.  How do i SET all rows in a table that end in .JPG to end in .PNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table x set pImage = replace(pImage, '.JPG', '.PNG')
```

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Be aware that this won't check that the '.JPG' is at the end of the string. I would guess it would be sufficient for the OP's need, but the question did specify replacing the end of the string, which this answer doesn't do.

Comment: True, to validate that, you'd need a more complicated regex replace function, such as the one here: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp  Still, considering the specific case, this seemed like less work.

Comment: Be careful! You probably should check for only for the end of the string.  Consider: if column pImage had a value of `FILES.JPGORDON.JPG` it would become `FILES.PNGORDON.PNG`.

Comment: just add a `WHERE pImage LIKE '%.JPG'`

Comment: That would find only files that end in .JPG.  However, it will still replaces ANY .JPG in the center of the filename, so Bob's FILES.JPGORDON.JPG problem would still exist.

Answer (score 0):

This update statement should do the update without the issue of worrying about the `FILES.PNGORDON.PNG` issue Bob-Duell has been raising in the comments.

```
UPDATE TABLE x
SET pImage CONCAT(SUBSTR(pImage, 1, LENGTH(pImage)-3), 'PNG')
WHERE pImage LIKE '%.JPG'
```

ie:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('FILES.JPGORDON.JPG', 1, LENGTH('FILES.JPGORDON.JPG')-3), 'PNG');

--result: FILES.JPGORDON.PNG
```